# Java swing not read file in folder window server 2008

Tags: java, swing, readfile

Java swing not read file in folder window server 2008
please help me.

```
 public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
    for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
            listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
        }
    }
}
final File folder = new File("C:\\folder_test");
listFilesForFolder(folder);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? If so share that also.

Comment: 1) Since this is marked 'Swing' I'd suggest to get the directory from a `JFileChooser`. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: 4) *"..please help me."* Please (form and) ask a question.

Comment: I run the above code in the window server it does not work.

Comment: of course it doesn't work. There is no class, and there is code outside of a method

Comment: *"I run the above code in the window server it does not work."* That tells us nothing that was not already obvious. Post an MCVE (that uses a file chooser). Copy/paste the stack trace. (Like I advised before you made that reply.)

Answer (score -2):

Here I found a solution, that should solve your problem:

```
 private BufferedReader br;

public ReadFileFromHardDrive() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String sCurrentLine;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\folder_test"));
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
    }
    br.close();
}
```

Here is some explanation:

[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)
[How to read file in Java – BufferedReader](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/)

Comment: are you just guessing what OP's problem is? OP did not ask a question nor explained his problem. He wrote a code that print each file names in a directory and subdirectory but you answer with a code that print a file content.

Comment: Java swing not read file in folder <--- Isn't that a explanation on whats not working?